# CRM 2011 Supported JScript vs Unsupported JScript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, jscript, dynamics-crm-online

When can I term JScript as supported? 
If I use only Xrm and OrganizationalData is it *supported*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having a read of:

- [Supported Extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx)

In particular:

> Form Scripting
>
> Microsoft JScript functions that are associated through the
>   customization tools to the available events in the form are supported.
>   Interaction with data in the form is supported when performed using
>   documented objects and methods available within the Xrm.Page.data
>   object. Interaction with the form appearance and behavior is supported
>   when performed using documented objects and methods available within
>   the Xrm.Page.ui object. However, any direct interaction with the HTML
>   Document Object Model (DOM) will probably not be upgradable. The
>   structure of forms and HTML elements used in the forms could change in
>   future releases.